# Replacing constraints on mysql db, one always fails

Tags: mysql, constraints

MySQL: 5.5.27

phpMyAdmin: one of the most recent versions

I have a db that contains, among other tables, these:

- member
- language
- member_language

As I created it in a hurry and had to populate it for testing purposes, I discovered belatedly that not all the constraints were as they should be. For example, **member_id** in the **member_language** table must obviously map to **mem_id** in the **member** table, and **language_id** in the **member_language** table must map to **lang_id** in the **language** table. So I recreated all 3 tables, then re-imported all the data into the copied tables: first member, then language, and finally member_language.

Then I tried to enforce the constraints on member_language, but it fails to create the fk constraint for **member.mem_id** which would link it to **member_language.member_id**. Each time it throws the

```
#1452 error - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbname`.`#sql-122f_bec4cef`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-122f_bec4cef_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `member` (`mem_id`))
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here?
Tks
SP

Comment: you're trying to insert a record into that table for which no corresponding record exists in the parent table.

Comment: but that's the weird thing - they DO all exist!

Comment: do a `show engine status innodb`. buried somewhere near the middle of the output will be more details about the foreign key error.

Comment: thanks so much. however i don't enough rights on this hosted db to do that. instead i started to take apart the tables one by one - see my answer for what i found!

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what the problem was.

There were indeed some member_id values missing from the member_language table. This may not be the ONLY problem, but certainly one problem is that the SQL Export file I created from phpMyAdmin skipped some values!!

This is really bizarre because I could see the values in Browse view while looking at the table, but on export, it missed lines from that table, here and there. So there were indeed mismatches, which I am assuming caused the problem.

Will post again if I find other possible reasons ...

Comment: And here's another thing: a few members did not have an entry in member_language, because of legacy data from a system that did not store this data for the first 18 months. I thought it had all been checked, but clearly not :-(. Lesson learned: in future I will make sure all legacy data with missing items will get assigned a default value, even if it evaluates to "unknown". In the long run this will save time.